# Definition of linear response kernel in terms of wavefunctions (Parr/Yang)

Tags: wavefunction, perturbation-theory, density-functional-theory

I'm trying to understand the derivation of the linear response kernel in Parr/Yang's "Density-functional theory of atoms and molecules".
First some background information:
We look at a system of $N$ electrons which are described by the Hamiltonian

\begin{equation}
H_\text{el}= -\frac{1}{2}\sum_i \nabla_i^2 + \sum_{i<j} \frac{1}{|\boldsymbol r_i - \boldsymbol r_j|} + \sum_i v(\boldsymbol r_i).
\end{equation}

Imagine the potential $v$ to be the Coulomb potential due to the nuclei in a molecule. We call the $k$-th eigenstate to this Hamiltonian $\Psi_k^{(0)} = \Psi_k^{(0)}(\boldsymbol x_1 \dots \boldsymbol x_N)$ (the (0) indicating that these are the "unperturbed" states, since we will introduce a perturbation soon). The $\boldsymbol x_i := (\boldsymbol r_i, m_{s, i})$ are collective spatial and spin degrees of freedom.

The electron density associated with the wavefunction $\Psi_k^{(0)}$ is defined as

\begin{equation}
\rho_k(\boldsymbol r_1) = N \int \Psi_k^{(0)*}\Psi_k^{(0)} dm_{s, 1} d\boldsymbol x_2 \dots d\boldsymbol x_N.
\end{equation}

Now we introduce a perturbation $\Delta V = \sum_i \Delta v(\boldsymbol r_i)$ to the Hamiltonian, which we assume to be small such that we can express our perturbed wavefunction by usual first-order time-independent perturbation theory: $\Psi_k = \Psi_k^{(0)}+\Psi_k^{(1)}$ (the first order correction being calculated via the well-known formula).

Parr/Yang then come (on page 15) to the following expression for the change of the electron density due to the perturbation:

\begin{align}
\Delta \rho_k(\boldsymbol r_1) &:= N \int \left(\Psi_k^*\Psi_k - \Psi_k^{(0)*}
\Psi_k^{(0)}  \right) dm_{s, 1} d\boldsymbol x_2 \dots d\boldsymbol x_N \\
&= 2N \Re\left[ \sum_{j\neq k} \frac{\langle \Psi_j^{(0)}| \Delta V | \Psi_k^{(0)}\rangle}{E_k^{(0)} - E_j^{(0)}} \int \Psi_k^{(0)*}\Psi_j^{(0)} dm_{s, 1} d\boldsymbol x_2 \dots d\boldsymbol x_N \right].
\end{align}

Up to here it is quite easy (simply ignore terms quadratic in the first-order correction). In the next line, however, they claim that

\begin{equation}
\Delta\rho_k(\boldsymbol r_1) = \int \chi_k(\boldsymbol r_1, \boldsymbol r_2) \Delta v(\boldsymbol r_2) d\boldsymbol r_2
\end{equation}
(this is the conventional definition of the object $\chi(\boldsymbol r_1, \boldsymbol r_2)$, which is called linear response kernel) with

\begin{equation}
\chi_k(\boldsymbol r_1, \boldsymbol r_2) = 2 N^2 \frac{\sum_{j\neq k}\left( \int\Psi_j^{(0)*}\Psi_k^{(0)} d\boldsymbol x_1 dm_{s, 2} \dots d\boldsymbol x_N  \right)\left( \int\Psi_k^{(0)*}\Psi_j^{(0)}  dm_{s, 1} \dots d\boldsymbol x_N  \right)}{E_k^{(0)} - E_j^{(0)}}.
\end{equation}

Knowing that

\begin{align}
\langle \Psi_j^{(0)}|\Delta V|\Psi_k^{(0)}\rangle &= \sum_i \int v(\boldsymbol r_i) \left[ \int \Psi_j^{(0)*}\Psi_k^{(0)} d\boldsymbol x_1 \dots dm_{s, i} \dots d\boldsymbol x_N \right] d\boldsymbol r_i \\
&= N \int v(\boldsymbol r_2) \left[ \int\Psi_j^{(0)*}\Psi_k^{(0)} d\boldsymbol x_1 dm_{s, 2} \dots d\boldsymbol x_N \right] d\boldsymbol r_2,
\end{align}
I can come to the exact same formula except that in my case there is still the $\Re$. My question is: Is this formula correct and I have missed something or have they forgotten the $\Re$?

Comment: 5 years is long for no answer, why not copy and paste on https://materials.stackexchange.com?